# Chrome extension: Keeping user preferences unchnaged after update?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, add-on

I'm writing a Chrome extension that keeps user preferences stored.

Here is the code I use in the background script to initialize the default value of one of the settings:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        mykey: true
    });
});
```

The problem is that onInstalled also executes after updates, so users preferences will get reset after an update. Is there a way to prevent execution for updates. Maybe an if statement in the listener?

Answer (score 0):

Searching around I have found this check:

`if (details.reason !== "update")`

So that would make my initial code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    if (details.reason !== "update") {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
            mykey: true
        });
    }
});
```

If anyone can confirm that this is a sure check that won't get bypassed in any certain cases, please let me know.